# Counterexample for $\lim \limits_{x \to c} \left\lvert f(x) \right\rvert = \left\lvert L \right\rvert$ then $\lim \limits_{x \to c} f(x) = L$

Tags: calculus, limits, examples-counterexamples

I know that the converse of this is true. I was looking for some counterexamples proving this statement false.

Comment: Take $f(x)=-1$, $x\to 0$, say.

Comment: The absolute value of the limit of the absolute value of f(x) would be 1, and the limit of f(x) = -1, whose absolute value is 1. I don't think this is a counterexample.

Comment: It is a counterexample if $L = 1$.

Comment: Are there any nontrivial cases where you don't just change the sign of the limit?

Comment: @RainbowJeremy You already got answers, but here are two more counterexamples: (1) $L=2$, $c=-2$ and $f(x)=x^2+x$; (2) $L=1$, $c=3\pi/2$ and $f(x)=\sin(x)$ (of course, they are trivial in your point of view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
-1 \text{ if } x\not\in \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$

Then $\lim\limits_{x\to 1} |f(x)|=1$ but $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}f(x)$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x) = -x$ and consider say $x \to 3$ then

$$
\lim_{x \to 3} |f(x)| =3 
$$
but this does not mean that

$$
\lim_{x \to 3 }f(x) = 3
$$
Other nice examples are given above.

Answer (score 1):

look at $$f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}.$$  we have $\lim_{x\to 0} |f(x)| = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ is undefined because $\lim_{x \to 0+}f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to 0-}f(x) = -1.$

Answer (score 0):

The Heaviside function can be defined as $H(x) =1$ for $x\ge 0$ and $H(x)=-1$ for $x<0$.  Clearly $\lim_{x\to 0}|H(x)|=1$, but $\lim_{x\to 0}H(x)$ does not exist since the left and right sided limits are of opposite sign.

In fact, this counter example falls into a class of functions with jump discontinuities with right and left sided limits of opposite sign.